# Make windows not remember network password?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get windows to forget a network password?](https://superuser.com/questions/88672/how-to-get-windows-to-forget-a-network-password)

is there a way to change the settings so that Windows does not remember the network password after it connects, so that upon disconnecting it won't reconnect without that password?

Comment: for windows vista and/or windows 7.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/88672/how-to-get-windows-to-forget-a-network-password exact duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Don't check "remember password" when you provide credentials.

To remove already stored credentials in XP and below;

```
control userpasswords2
```

The dialogue has changed somewhat in Vista/7, ("the vault") but I think it provides the same functionality.

Comment: On Windows 7 the vault interface can be found via typing `manage network passwords` or `credential manager` into the search box in the Start Menu.

Comment: userpasswords2 is nicely backwards compatible down to XP though =).

Answer (score 0):

net use /persistent:no
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx

Create a script to add the ones you want for your logon session.  Great applet for a powershell alias.

Comment: She's not asking about mapping a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a wireless network in Windows Vista, simply clear the box **Save this network** and the details will not be stored.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As in your other question -

Yes, there are a few ways.

First, from an elevated (Windows Vista and 7) command prompt type:

> `Net use * /delete`

Next, if the password is cached, go to Start > Run and type `control userpasswords2`, you should be able to click on the `Advanced` tab and then click on the `Manage Passwords` button to delete.

Alternatively you can use [Nirsoft Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) and delete any saved password from there.

If again you are talking about Wireless network passwords and not Windows network resource passwords.

For Windows XP, simply go to "Network Connections" and right click your Wireless card, look for the middle tab `Wireless Networks` and under preferred networks, simply press delete on the correct one.

[image]

For Windows Vista and 7, Go to `Network and Sharing Center` and click `Manage Wireless Networks` then simply delete the networks you no longer want to connect to.

[image]

[image]

If you do not want to connect to a network automatically in the future, remember to uncheck the box `Save this Network`

Also, Nirsoft again make a good tool the works on all Windows versions., [Nirsoft Wireless Key View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)

Comment: "If you do not want to connect to a network automatically in the future, remember to uncheck the box Save this Network" ... you're at it again? you may want to have a look at my answer and the time of posting.

Comment: this question is not about removing networks but windows 'not remembering passwords' and the only part of your answer relevant to the question is a blatant copy ... again.

Comment: @Molly, FFS.... It took me more than a minute to get all those pictures up, I started writing before... I would say more, but I really just can't be bothered.

Comment: @Molly, doing the "Save this network" checkbox and then deleting the network result in the EXACT same outcome... no network remembered on disconnection.

Comment: it's just getting a bit obvious now, my good man. you may want to work on your style. while you were typing your answer, i'm sure you saw a popup asking you to 'Load new answer?' yet you decided to go ahead. you're around long enough to have learned how SU works. you wish to second an answer, upvote it, it's the decent thing to do.

Comment: @Molly ... Your answer is one hour after BlueNovembers, he has written pretty much the same thing... Do you want me to start saying you copied him?

Comment: i certainly do not see any references to "Save this network" in BlueNovember's answer, sorry.