# Make Windows forget a network connection password?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, passwords

Is there a way to prevent Windows from remembering the network password after it connects? So that upon disconnecting Windows won't reconnect without re-entering password.

What if I want it to always delete it...not just by manual means. That is, I'm trying to restrict my usage of the Internet by giving someone else a password. I can only use the Internet if I get a password from them, but when I disconnect, my "session" is done. I don't want it so that I can simply reconnect without having to input the password.

Comment: You should associate your StackOverflow and SuperUser accounts.

Comment: woops my bad i'm new at this (clearly).
-poop

Comment: BlueNovember meant ( http://superuser.com/questions/88668/make-windows-not-remember-network-password )

Comment: This can occur when Windows errors on connecting to a wireless network by saying: `Windows cannot connect to wireless network`. I fixed it by following one of the answers below to remove the wireless network in question.

Comment: @poop, why is your name poop?

Answer (score 21):

To delete wireless networks in Windows Vista, go to **Control Panel**, **Network and Sharing Center**, under **Tasks** click **Manage Wireless Networks**.

[image]

Delete the networks you don't want to be stored  (right click -> **Remove Network**).

[image]

> I don't want it so that I can simply
>   reconnect without having to input the
>   password.

The next time you connect to a wireless network, simply clear the box **Save this network**, and the details will not be stored.

[image]

Comment: what if i want it to always delete it...not just by manual means.  i.e. i'm trying to restrict my usage of internet by giving someone else password.  i can only use internet if i get password from them, but when i disconnect, my "session" is done.  i dont want it so that i can simply reconnect w/o having to input the password.

Comment: btw ur suggestion doesn't work...

Comment: do you mean wireless networks? and which Windows version are you using?

Comment: wireless networks, yes.  windows vista.

Comment: watch for multiple copies of the same network (presumably from when the passwords were changed in the past). I had to delete a second copy of the network hidden at the end of the list before this worked

Comment: Works for Win 7

Answer (score 7):

Run "Credential Manager" (**Start** > type its name and choose in the filtered list ( for vista, 7)).
Remove the corresponding credentials you need from the credentials list.
Or **Control Panel** -> **User Accounts** -> **Manage Your Credentials**.
Or **Control Panel** -> **Credential Manager**.

Comment: I know the other answerers are answering a different question, but this is the answer I came here looking for! Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are a few ways.

First, from an elevated (Windows Vista and 7) command prompt type:

> `Net use * /delete`

Next, if the password is cached, go to Start > Run and type `control userpasswords2`, you should be able to click on the `Advanced` tab and then click on the `Manage Passwords` button to delete.

Alternatively you can use [Nirsoft Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) and delete any saved password from there.

### EDIT

Seen you have said you want to delete wireless keys, not Windows network keys.

For Windows XP, simply go to "Network Connections" and right click your Wireless card, look for the middle tab `Wireless Networks` and under preferred networks, simply press delete on the correct one.

[image]

For Windows Vista and 7, [BlueNovember wrote the correct way of doing it.](https://superuser.com/questions/88672/how-to-get-windows-to-forget-a-network-password/88685#88685)

Also, Nirsoft again make a good tool the works on all Windows versions., [Nirsoft Wireless Key View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)

Comment: I've found that you need to remove the old wireless keys from the registry. I've outlined it here: http://superuser.com/a/665877/7018

Answer (score 4):

For XP and below see [Wil's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88672/how-to-get-windows-to-forget-a-network-password/88677#88677).

For Vista/Windows7;

```
Control Panel
Network and Sharing Centre
Manage Wireless Networks
<Delete network>
```

Comment: +1, don't know why I wrote that, I just assumed he was using XP :S... I won't add your answer to mine, but I will just edit to say XP only, and say that the Nirsoft program works with all.

Comment: "I won't add your answer to mine" ... now, that is very nice of you :)